# How do I retrieve the angle between two vectors 3D?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, computational-geometry

I am new in python.
I have two vectors in 3d space, and I want to know the angle between two

I tried:

```
vec1=[x1,y1,z1]

vec2=[x2,y2,z2]

angle=np.arccos(np.dot(vec1,vec2)/(np.linalg.norm(vec1)*np.linalg.norm(vec2)))
```

but when change the order, vec2,vec1 obtain the same angle and no higher.
I want to give me a greater angle when the order of the vectors changes.

Comment: Have you decided how to figure out which normal you want to rotate around?

Answer (score 11):

Use a function to help you choose which angle do you want. In the beggining of your code, write:

```
def angle(v1, v2, acute):
# v1 is your firsr vector
# v2 is your second vector
    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(v1, v2) / (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2)))
    if (acute == True):
        return angle
    else:
        return 2 * np.pi - angle
```

Then, when you want to calculate an angle (in radians) in your program just write

```
angle(vec1, vec2, 'True')
```

for acute angles, and

```
angle(vec2, vec1, 'False')
```

for obtuse angles.

For example:

```
vec1 = [1, -1, 0]
vec2 = [1, 1, 0]

#I am explicitly converting from radian to degree
print(180* angle(vec1, vec2, True)/np.pi) #90 degrees
print(180* angle(vec2, vec1, False)/np.pi) #270 degrees
```

Comment: The one thing to be aware of is that `np.dot(v1, v2) / (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2))` may return something like `1.0000000000000002` if `v1` and `v2` are perfectly colinear. In this case the `np.arccos(...)` will throw an ugly runtime warning. This issue can be avoided by using `np.arccos(np.clip(...,-1,1))`

Comment: What if you need the angle in 3d space - [0, 90, 0]deg

Answer (score 10):

If you're working with 3D vectors, you can do this concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

vec1 = np.array([x1, y1, z1])
vec2 = np.array([x2, y2, z2])

vg.angle(vec1, vec2)
```

You can also specify a viewing angle to compute the angle via projection:

```
vg.angle(vec1, vec2, look=vg.basis.z)
```

Or compute the signed angle via projection:

```
vg.signed_angle(vec1, vec2, look=vg.basis.z)
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are verbose or opaque in NumPy.

Comment: Tested it quickly - this is quite useful. Things that I have used at least are nothing super fancy, but just as the docs says - I don't want to have to write a function to normalize vectors, then compute angle then.... Pretty happy to be using that to prototype stuff. If anything I can later re-implement/optimize if needed for whatever reason. Loving it

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is impossible as the plane that contains the angle can be oriented two ways and nothing in the input data gives a clue about it.

All you can do is to compute the smallest angle between the vectors (or its complement to 360°), and swapping the vectors can't have an effect.

The dot product isn't guilty here, this is a geometric dead-end.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product is commutative, so you'll have to use a different metric. It doesn't care about the order.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dot product is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties), simply reversing the order you put the variables into the function will not work.

If your objective is to find the obtuse(larger) angle rather than the acute(smaller) one, subtract the value returned by your function from 360 degrees. Since you seem to have a criteria for when you want to switch the variables around, you should use that same criteria to determine when to subtract your found value from 360. This will give you the value you are looking for in these cases.

Comment: yes, but how automatize that process in a program in python, I no have idea. this a part of main program that calculate if a point is inside that poligone with vertex in a space 3d. a therorem say that addition of angles between the vector generate for the point and vertex is =n*360 degrees.

Comment: You were saying that you were switching the order of the vectors. What was the intended result of this? Under what circumstances would you want to switch those vectors? Answering these questions will help me to help you.

Comment: @AlbertoAlarconParedes which theorem are you referring to? The total internal angle of a polygon is 180*(n-2) degrees.