# Finding the angle between all positive and negative combinations of two 3D vectors

Tags: python, numpy, computational-geometry

Following [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497496/how-do-i-retrieve-the-angle-between-two-vectors-3d?rq=1) for calculating the angle between two 3D angles, I want to expand it in a way that it calculates all the possible positive and negative combinations of the angles.

For instance I have the following code from the same link that calculates the angle between the (1,1,5) and (-1,1,2):

```
import numpy as np
import vg

vec1 = np.array([1, 1, 5])
vec2 = np.array([-1, 1, 2])

angle= vg.angle(vec1, vec2)
print(angle)
```

Now I want a small function that calculates all the possible comibations of positive and negatives of each vector and gives a list of all the angles.

For instance it calculates the following pairs: (1,1,5)(-1,1,2), (1,1,-5)(-1,1,2), (1,-1,-5)(-1,1,2) etc. This seems to be quite easy but I couldn't figure it out.

Side question: how I can ask the `input()` function to get a vector? I know how it works for strings and numbers but can you ask it to get the input data in a special format from user? Like (1,2,3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vec_comb[:,:3]` has all the combinations of `vec1`, and `vec_comb[:,3:]` has all the combinations for `vec2`

```py
import numpy as np
import vg
import itertools


vec1 = np.array([1, 1, 5])
vec2 = np.array([-1, 1, 2])

vec_concat = np.hstack((vec1, vec2))


l = [1,-1]
comb = np.array(list(itertools.product(l, repeat=vec_concat.shape[0])))

vec_comb = np.einsum('i, ji -> ji', vec_concat, comb)
angle_comb = vg.angle(vec_comb[:,:3], vec_comb[:, 3:])
print(angle_comb)
```

Output:

```
[ 38.2169233  141.7830767   51.05755873 160.52877937  19.47122063
 128.94244127  38.2169233  141.7830767  141.7830767   38.2169233
 160.52877937  51.05755873 128.94244127  19.47122063 141.7830767
  38.2169233   51.05755873 160.52877937  38.2169233  141.7830767
  38.2169233  141.7830767   19.47122063 128.94244127 160.52877937
  51.05755873 141.7830767   38.2169233  141.7830767   38.2169233
 128.94244127  19.47122063  19.47122063 128.94244127  38.2169233
 141.7830767   38.2169233  141.7830767   51.05755873 160.52877937
 128.94244127  19.47122063 141.7830767   38.2169233  141.7830767
  38.2169233  160.52877937  51.05755873  38.2169233  141.7830767
  19.47122063 128.94244127  51.05755873 160.52877937  38.2169233
 141.7830767  141.7830767   38.2169233  128.94244127  19.47122063
 160.52877937  51.05755873 141.7830767   38.2169233 ]
```

Comment: Thanks @paul-shuvno, how can I now clean the data to remove the similar figures? For example (1,1,5) and (-1,-1,-5) are same directions and can be avoided in order not to create repetitive angles. [this is not super important to clean the results, I am just trying to learn]



@pakpe: the following line causes an error for me: ```angles = [vg.angle(item[0], item[1]) for item in combos]```

Comment: So, I need to know for debugging purposes, how many of the 64 angles above are repetitions?

Comment: I believe there are only 8 unique combinations

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: After creating the 8 variants of each vector, itertools.product() is used to find all pairwise combinations of all variants. The two items within each combnination are first converted back to np.arrays before they are fed to vg.angle() to construct all the angles.

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import vg

vector1 = np.array([1,1,5])
vector2 = np.array([-1,-1,2])

def vector_variants(vector):
    pairs = [[i, -i] for i in vector]
    return [[i,j,k] for i in pairs[0] for j in pairs[1] for k in pairs[2]]

v1_variants = vector_variants(vector1)
v2_variants = vector_variants(vector2)

combos = list(it.product(v1_variants, v2_variants))
angles = [vg.angle(np.array(item[0]), np.array(item[1])) for item in combos]
```

Finally, all 64 vector combinations and their corresponding angles can be displaced nicely as a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([(item[0], item[1], vg.angle(np.array(item[0]), np.array(item[1])))
                   for item in combos],columns=['v1', 'v2','angle'])
print(df)

#output:
              v1            v2       angle
0      [1, 1, 5]   [-1, -1, 2]   51.057559
1      [1, 1, 5]  [-1, -1, -2]  160.528779
2      [1, 1, 5]    [-1, 1, 2]   38.216923
3      [1, 1, 5]   [-1, 1, -2]  141.783077
4      [1, 1, 5]    [1, -1, 2]   38.216923
..           ...           ...         ...
59  [-1, -1, -5]   [-1, 1, -2]   38.216923
60  [-1, -1, -5]    [1, -1, 2]  141.783077
61  [-1, -1, -5]   [1, -1, -2]   38.216923
62  [-1, -1, -5]     [1, 1, 2]  160.528779
63  [-1, -1, -5]    [1, 1, -2]   51.057559

[64 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Changing the line `combos = list(it.product(v1_variants, v2_variants))` to `combos = np.array(it.product(v1_variants, v2_variants))` should fix the error.

Comment: Still I get the following error: TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Comment: @Reza. I fixed it. See the updated answer. I also put all the resulting vectors and their corresponding angles in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Unless some component is zero, every vector yields eight distinct vectors by changing the signs.

This apparently results in 8 x 8 = 64 combinations, but in fact only 32 are distinct because the angle bewteen u, v and between -u, -v are identical.

For implementation, I would simply hard-code the options by hand in two lists (one among the signs is not changed) and double-loop on the pairs.