# Find angular components between 2 vectors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vector, scipy, linear-algebra

How to find angle between 2 vector using python, preferably `numpy` or `scipy`; in terms of components of rotation about `x,y,z` axes?

For example in the code below, utilizing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533085/17471060), we can find the angle between 2 vectors.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5,7,5])-np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([3.25842, 8.14983, 4.44192])-np.array([1,2,3])

def angle(v1, v2, acute):
    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(v1, v2) / (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2)))
    if (acute == True):
        return angle
    else:
        return 2 * np.pi - angle

print(np.rad2deg(angle(v1=a, v2=b, acute=True)))
# returns: 18.531657948873978
```

Desired angles are `alpha_` `x,y,z` components.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [SciPy Rotation API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html).

If you have two vectors, you can find the rotation between them with `Rotation.align_vectors()`. SciPy then gives you six choices for how to represent the rotation. (See the documentation, and the six methods beginning with `as_`, for a list of which output formats you can use.)

The one which seems most similar to your question is [Euler angles](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.as_euler.html).

Example:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
rot, rssd = Rotation.align_vectors(a, b)
print(rot.as_euler('XYZ', degrees=True))
```

Output:

```
[  6.7385178    0.60887791 -17.29830824]
```

Notes:

- `as_euler()` accepts an order of angles, and doing the rotations in a different order can give different results. I recommend reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) to understand why.
- `as_euler()` gives you a choice between intrinsic and extrinsic rotation angles. Use `rot.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)` for extrinsic angles.
- The rssd variable returned by `align_vectors()` represents distance between vectors after the rotation. See [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors.html) for more.